# Rocket.Chat live chat not support the internal hubot

Tags: hubot, rocket.chat

I have added the internal hubot to the live chat agent, but it doesn't response any message.

I have tested the internal hubot in other channels, it works well.

Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Comment: Could you find any solution on this?

Comment: @Amir seem the latest version supports it, but I haven't used the rocket.chat for a long while.